# Android get image from camera always return 0 orientation

Tags: android

get image from camera, the orientation always return 0

```
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
        lCursor = Application.getAppContext().getContentResolver()
        .query(lSelectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        lCursor.moveToFirst();
        lColumnIndex = lCursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        lFilePath = lCursor.getString(lColumnIndex);
        lOrientation = lCursor.getInt(1);
        Log.d("Orientation = ",String.valueOf(lOrientation));
        lCursor.close();
```

Do you know how to get orientation when get image from camera? thank you